# how to get href from a list of tags using python script?

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a html file 'links.html', from this html file i want to extract href **//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand- 
details/8414/capicare**, which is for the string **CAPICARE**.
How to this using a python script

Code of 'links.html' is :

```
<a itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand- 
details/12220/cholstig"><span itemprop="name">CHOLSTIG</span></a>
<a itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand- 
details/8414/capicare"><span itemprop="name">CAPICARE</span></a>
<a itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand- 
details/230/cyclozobid"><span itemprop="name">CYCLOZOBID</span></a>
<a itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand- 
details/6855/cinkona"><span itemprop="name">CINKONA</span></a>
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish that task with a "simple" regex which takes advantage of capture (and non-capture) groups:

```py
import re

html = ('<a itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand'
        '-details/12220/cholstig"><span itemprop="name">CHOLSTIG</span></a><a '
        'itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand-details'
        '/8414/capicare"><span itemprop="name">CAPICARE</span></a><a '
        'itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand-details'
        '/230/cyclozobid"><span itemprop="name">CYCLOZOBID</span></a><a '
        'itemprop="url" href="//www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand-details'
        '/6855/cinkona"><span itemprop="name">CINKONA</span></a>')

regex = '(?:href=")([^"]+)(?:.*?<span.*?>)(.*?)(?:</span>)'

matches = re.findall(regex, html)

for m in matches:
    print(f'Brand: {m[1]}, URL: {m[0]}')
```

This will output the following:

```
Brand: CHOLSTIG, URL: //www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand-details/12220/cholstig
Brand: CAPICARE, URL: //www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand-details/8414/capicare
Brand: CYCLOZOBID, URL: //www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand-details/230/cyclozobid
Brand: CINKONA, URL: //www.medicineindia.org/medicine-brand-details/6855/cinkona
```

Which is formatted output from iterating over the list of tuples, `matches`, where the link is matched with it's corresponding 'span' contents.

Comment: The solution given by you is not working.
Actually , i have to extract that link from 'tags', and i have created 'tags' from following code:

    url= some_url...
    response = requests.get(url)
    # Extracting the source code of the page.
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

    title_bn = CAPICORE


    # Extracting all the <a> tags into a list.
    tags = soup.find_all('a')

Now from tags i need to extract that link for CAPICORE

Comment: If instead of extracting all the links, you parse the HTML from `response.text` into a string and run the findall with the multiline flag, then it will work.

Comment: Plus, if you are utilizing BeautifulSoup, then why are you parsing HTML as "LXML"?